# How to set a global environment variable in .NET Core (user-wide or system-wide)

Tags: c#, environment-variables, cross-platform, .net-core

In full .NET we can pass `EnvironmentVariableTarget` enum to `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` call:

```
public enum EnvironmentVariableTarget
{
    Process,
    User,
    Machine
}
```

With `User` or `Machine` options we can set a user-wide or system-wide variable which stays live after application end:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("foo", "bar", EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

...

```
> echo %foo%
bar
```

However, `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable` doesn't accept the variable target in .NET Core. Even XML comment for this method says:

> Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored in the current **process**.

How to set an user-wide or machine-wide environment variable in .NET Core-targeted app? Only a crossplatform solution makes sense (at least Windows and Linux).

Comment: Most linux distributions have different mechanisms of setting environment variables. mac also has it's own (though similar to many linux flavours). You'll need to look at what your target system needs, there is no true cross-platform solution here - i guess only the windows one is the real pain here (on linux it's mostly adding a file in a known location).

Answer (score 3):

For .NET Core 1.x it only allows setting an environment variable in the User context. With the new .NET Core 2.0 preview it allows using the `EnvironmentVariableTarget`. However, according to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/20147) GitHub issue setting User or Machine environment variables doesn't work on non-windows platforms.

> Using other scopes (e.g. User, Machine) on non-Windows platforms) is not mapped in the implementation.

Also described in the GitHub issue is to use a workaround to check if it is a non-windows platform to set an environment variable. For example:

```
// omitting check for presence of bash binary
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux)) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/bin/bash", "-c export " + variable + "=" + value);
```

Comment: Recently I checked that GitHub issue once again... the workaround you quote doesn't work. It is even mentioned in comments below.

Comment: does this still not support linux?