# How can I pass the exit code of a dotnet core application out of a docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

**This is no longer an issue**

The problem was most likely caused by some caching problem in Visual Studio.
It was fixed by recreating the solution and re-adding Docker support.

=========================================================================

I have a small dotnet core application that is supposed to help with end to end tests.

To be able to integrate it with our CI pipeline I put it into a docker container 
and up to this point things are working out OK.

Now the problem is that docker container does not exit with the same code as the application does.

I assume this is because the application is encapsulated by the dotnet runtime, so even if the application exits with a non-zero code the actual entry point (`dotnet`) as defined in the `Dockerfile`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DataComparerCli.dll"]
```

exits with `0x0` and this is what is used as the exit code of the container.

I tried to work around this by having the application store its exit code in an environment variable and creating a shell script as entry point which then calls dotnet in turn and uses the application's exit code as its own but this currently fails.

```
#!/bin/bash

dotnet /app/path/to/dll/DataComparerCli.dll
exit $DataComparerExitCode
```

It feels like I'm using a (broken) crutch and that this is the reason why I can't get this to work.

Is this the a good approach and I'm just having issues with the bash script or are there better ways to get this to work?

**UPDATE**
Apparently it is currently (version 3.1 preview) not possible to set environment variables that outlive the application on mac and linux:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44248788/2137237

Comment: It's impossible for *any* application to set an environment variable that outlives its own process. The "environment" part of the "environment variable" refers to the environment of the process and its children.

Comment: Can you try this with a hello-world style application? Only do an `Environment.Exit(1)` in `Main`. Please include the entire project file, source code dockerfile and how you are building and running the dockerfile.

Comment: I did and the disturbing truth is, that the MCVE does what I want. The docker container exits with the hardcoded value in `Environment.Exit()`. I guess I'll have to rebuild the whole solution. Adding my files step by step and then redo the Docker and Compose support :(

Answer (score 2):

It should be the exit status of the process, as there is no code like `0x0` from docker exit code, so it is the dotnet that return `0x0`. You can look into these link.

[The program '[3984] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450751 (0x80008081)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672371/the-program-3984-dotnet-exe-has-exited-with-code-2147450751-0x80008081/49888829)

[The thread has exited with code 0 (0x0) with no unhandled exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410548/the-thread-has-exited-with-code-0-0x0-with-no-unhandled-exception)

Here is the list of docker exit code.

```
125: docker run itself fails
126: contained command cannot be invoked
127: if contained command cannot be found
128 + n Fatal error signal n:
130 = (128+2) Container terminated by Control-C
137 = (128+9) Container received a SIGKILL
143 = (128+15) Container received a SIGTERM
```

[What is the authoritative list of Docker Run exit codes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297616/what-is-the-authoritative-list-of-docker-run-exit-codes)

Here is the simplest way to reproduce using nodejs

```
FROM node:alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chmod +x /app/start.sh
entrypoint /app/start.sh
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
node start.js
```

js script

```
let exitCode = 45;
console.log("server is going to shutdown");
process.exit(exitCode)
```

So I can see the correct code.

[image]

So the issue is not related to docker, but the dotnet process it self.

Answer (score 0):

Docker always return the exit code of the process that was executed, unless some other errors were detected related to the daemon itself. This means that `dotnet DataComparerCli.dll` should be returning the correct exit code.

The problem is probably the way you are running the container. How are you doing so? If you use detached mode `-d`, the exit code will always be 0 for the process.

For example:

```
$ docker run busybox /bin/sh -c 'exit 3' 
$ echo $?
# 3
$ docker run -d busybox /bin/sh -c 'exit 3'
$ echo $?
# 0
```